# Multiple run and data input on an exe

Tags: excel, vba, cmd, exe

I am not an experienced programmer so please sorry if my explanation is not using proper terms, but I can always clarify if its not clear.

-I have an exe program and I want to be able to use this program to perform multiple analyses

-The program import a txt file and export a txt file

-The usual process of using the program is: it opens a GUI window and requires clicking of some menu buttons to import a txt and export another txt file

Since I dont have the source code of the program, is it possible to use cmd (or anything else) so that I can create an Excel macro to automate this process?

Any suggestion is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You can call / show an exe from Excel. But you are at the mercy of whatever functionality is baked into the EXE. i.e. you can't just automate the EXE unless someone already built that capability into it.

Or you could try something like `sendkeys` to make it work, but that is generally unreliable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-start-an-application-and-send-it-keystrokes

A more reliable UI automation program is `AutoIt`. Also I believe there is windows native app that does this but can't remember it's name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick. I thought I would still be able to automate the EXE, so your answer already removes that option from the table which is very helpful. Why is sendkeys generally unreliable?

Comment: Sendkeys is like shooting arrrows into the dark - it presses keys on whatever window is active. So if someone brings a different window up, sendkeys will be sent to that. Also there is no feedback. So if you sendkey a tab to move into another field, but that tab doesn't work (because there is some form validation you didn't think of), there's no way to tell. `AutoIt` is much more reliable because you can explicitly select windows controls rather than blindly typing things into the dark with no feedback

Comment: There's always an inherent risk in any of these automation solutions because you are running "interactively".... for example a windows update message might pop up and take focus and you might happen to be sending an `enter` at the time and it will just restart. Again `AutoIt` is a bit more reliable here.

Comment: What does the EXE do, and how does Excel come into this? Are there other things you need Excel for, or is it just to be used as a platform to run it from? If you can run it all from AutoIt instead of excel you'll have more luck. Also if you want to check for command line switches you could try opening a command prompt and try some of these things: `MyFile.EXE /?` `MyFile.EXE -?` `MyFile.EXE -help` `MyFile.EXE -h`

Comment: You can also use this method to check if it exposes a COM interface, but I'm guessing the program is not sophisticated enough to do that (or the command line thing) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference

Comment: it is a structural design program, it has a very simple GUI interface and its release date is 2010.. my guess is that it's probably written in C (not sure if that is an useful info). I need to use Excel at least to create the txt to be imported and read the txt exported by the program because that is what my coworkers use

Comment: Does the program have a name? because the next thing i would do is google it and see if supports a COM interface or command line switches

Comment: about -? -h -help and /?. I run and cmd only opens the program, nothing else is displayed..

Comment: I made a search on the program by its name and I can't find much other than manuals and people asking questions about it. very limited number of results.

Comment: So do you have to click buttons in the EXE, and does that button have a shortcut key? If it does, you can try `sendkeys` from VBA. If you have to click a button, and that button _doesn't_ have ashortcut key, you have to use AutoIt, but that is more reliable and you can probably call it from Excel VBA